# Create a connection script: should I use unset?

Tags: php, mysqli

I was learning from this great article, specifically on how to create a connection script in PHP:
https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/mysqli_connect

But, the article defines the `unset` differently in 2 places. I'm confused.
For example, in the beginning of the article it says:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $dbname, $port);
    $db->set_charset($charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
}
unset($host, $dbname, $user, $pass, $charset); // we don't need them anymore
```

and at the end:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
try {
    require __DIR__.'/db_credentials.php';
    $db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db, $port);
    $db->set_charset($charset);
} catch (\mysqli_sql_exception $e) {
     throw new \mysqli_sql_exception($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode());
} finally {
    unset($host, $db, $user, $pass, $charset);
}
```

So, which is it? Should I use `unset`? If yes, how... with or without the keyword `finally`?

Great articles, by the way.

Comment: they are virtually the same and there is no real necessity to `unset` them once they have served their purpose in making the connection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases `unset` acts the same way - frees up the parameters for the database connection.

What is different? Syntax only.

`finally` is a way to make sure that even when an error occours, the code inside the `finally` block will run.

The code only with `try` and `catch` will operate the same way. After the catch `unset` will run.

Both are correct.

You can read about the small differences regarding `finally` [here](https://www.texelate.co.uk/blog/how-to-use-the-finally-keyword-in-php#:%7E:text=The%20finally%20keyword%20relates%20to,and%20before%20normal%20execution%20resumes.).